# simplexml: access attribute country's value

Tags: php, simplexml

I need to access attribute country's value (without using xpath) from the following:
http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/79.6.54.99.xml

This is what I have done so far

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/79.6.54.99.xml");
$country = $xml->objects->object->attributes->attribute ... ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found two ways to do it, with [ ] and with attributes().

```
foreach(simplexml_load_file("http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/79.6.54.99.xml")->objects->object->attributes->attribute as $a){
if($a['name'] == 'country')
if(in_array($a['value'],array('IT'))) exit;
else break;
}
```

I'll leave this question open till tomorrow just in case anyone else has something up his/her sleeve.

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/79.6.54.99.xml');
foreach ($xml->objects->object->attributes->attribute as $attr) {
   if ($attr->attributes()->name == 'country') {
      echo $attr->attributes()->value;
   }
}
```

Comment: this won't work without type casting.

Comment: I got it to working without type casting. See PHP's documented example http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: true, it was just xdebug showing me an empty SimpleXMLElement object.

Answer (score 0):

This works;

```
$s = simplexml_load_file("http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/79.6.54.99.xml");
foreach ($s->objects->object->attributes->attribute as $attr) {
    $attrs = $attr->attributes();
    if ((string) $attrs->name == "country") {
        $country = (string) $attrs->value;
        break;
    }
}
print $country; // IT
```

But there is an option too, if it's suitable for you;

```
$s = file_get_contents("http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/79.6.54.99.xml");
preg_match_all('~<attribute\s+name="country"\s+value="(.*?)".*?/>~i', $s, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Out;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <attribute name="country" value="IT"/>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => IT
        )

)
```